# SQL query for getting data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

A MySQL question, apologize for being a beginner. I would like to get data from 3 different tables, as you can see in the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrvWB.jpg).

The given company maintains the employees' travels, but for technical reasons, in two different tables. Two types of travel are possible. If the employee chooses the first one, it's stored in the first table. Only this kind of travels are stored in this table. If he chooses the second one, it's stored in the second table, together with several other types of working times. (The difference between the two travel types is tax related, but that's out of interest here.) I would like to generate a 3 column result set which shows the travel days for everybody in this year (see the screenshot above). It's difficult to use either SUM or COUNT, because the data structure is quite different in the two tables. I tried to use the SQL query below, but that just unions the two different query what I would like to merge instead. I would like to see all emplyees in the result set, regardless if they travelled at all. If they didn't, I would like to see NULL values there.

```
SELECT Employees.Name as name1, SUM(TravelType1.TravelDurationDays) as Travel FROM `Employees` INNER JOIN `TravelType1` ON Employees.EmployeeID=TravelType1.EmployeeID WHERE (TravelType1.StartTime>='01.01.2015' and TravelType1.EndTime<='31.12.2015') GROUP BY Employees.Name

UNION

SELECT Employees.Name as name1, COUNT(*) as Travel FROM `Employees` INNER JOIN `TravelType1` ON Employees.EmployeeID=TravelType2.EmployeeID WHERE TravelType2.TravelDay>='01.01.2015' and TravelType2.TravelDay<='31.12.2015' and TravelType2.Travel='yes' GROUP BY Employees.Name
```

I'm not sure it's possible at all in one SQL statement, because of the really different data format in the two source tables. I already tried some conbinations of LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN, but could't achieve anything yet.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use a select statement in the place of a table name in the FROM part of a query.  So I would `select * from (select ... from employee inner join traveltype1 on ... where ...) outer join (select ... from employee inner join traveltype2 on ... where ...) on ...` so that you can get both results in the same row.

Comment: Or you could join all three tables in one query using left joins to the employee table: `select * from employee left join traveltype1 on ... left join traveltype2 on ... where ...`

Comment: Could you post the create table commands for the three tables so we can work on this and actually answer with working sql?

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, Jerry, maraca prvoded me with the perfect solution, so there is no reason for pasting the Create Table commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with 2 sub-selects:

```
SELECT
   e.Name,
   (SELECT
      SUM(TravelDurationDays)
   FROM
      TravelType1
   WHERE
      EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
   ) TravelType1Days,
   (SELECT
      COUNT(*)
   FROM
      TravelType2
   WHERE
      EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID AND
      Travel = 'yes'
   ) TravelType2Days
FROM
   Employees e
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented with joins.

```
SELECT e.Name, 
  SUM(TravelType1.TravelDurationDays), 
  SUM(IF(TravelType2.Travel = 'yes' and TravelType2.Day >= '01.01.2015' and TravelType2.Day <= '31.12.2015', 1, 0))
FROM Employees e 
  LEFT JOIN TravelType1 ON e.EmployeeID = TravelType1.EmployeeID
  LEFT JOIN TravelType2 ON e.EmployeeID = TravelType2.EmployeeID
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID;
```